# Should allowing multiple DVs to covary in SEM influence beta coefficients?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, covariance, structural-equation-modeling, path-model, amos

I am running a replication study to test a model with 8 IVs and 3 DVs (all variables are continuous).

In the initial study, I had a moderate sample (≈ 200), and thus relied upon multivariate multiple regression.

In this replication study, my sample is considerably larger (≈ 1500).

Importantly, the 3 DVs are moderately correlated (*r* = .10 to .50), and I have been advised to use SEM to help control for the inter-correlation between the DVs.

I downloaded AMOS, constructed my path model, and convaried the error terms for the DVs.

This was my first attempt at SEM path analysis, though to my surprise, the beta coefficients were exactly the same as when I ran 3 test regression analyses (one for each DV) separately.

I appreciate that this is a beginners question, but where have I gone wrong?

Have I:

a) ran the model incorrectly

b) misunderstood how I should control for the covariance between the DVs

c) misunderstood the effect that controlling for covariance should have on the results

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I think (c).

Allowing the outcomes to covary is appropriate. If you don't, the model is wrong (and you'd see this in the fit statistics).

Your results should  (very close to) exactly the same as if you did a multivariate regression - which isn't a surprise, as you fitted the same model. (And by results I mean estimates, standard errors, CIs, etc).